# How to change nullable columns to having default values in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration, nullable, default-value, doctrine-dbal

I want to change some table columns in Laravel from nullable to having a default value. I installed doctrine/dbal, and created a new migration with the following columns I want to change (previously nullable):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('movieDirector')->default('')->change();
            $table->string('movieGenre')->default('')->change();
            $table->string('movieCast')->default('')->change();
        });
    }
```

However this doesn't seem to have done anything. Is it possible to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new migration using command:

```
php artisan make:migration update_movies_table
```

Then, in that created migration class, add this line, using the `change` method like this :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('movieDirector')->default('test')->change();
            $table->string('movieGenre')->default('test')->change();
            $table->string('movieCast')->default('test')->change();
        });
    }
```

To make these changes and run the migration, use the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```